# SqlAnywhere 12- service started but stopped

Tags: sybase-sql-anywhere

I've been running my *db file on Windows 7 platform. Rrcently I have encountered a problem where I try to revoke the SqlAnywhere server but I received this error:

> The Sql Anywhere- myserv service on local computer started and then stopped. Some services stop automatically if they are not in use by other services or programs.

Kindly help.

Answer (score 1):

If you are still having problems with this, the first place to look is in the Windows Application Events log - you should see the reason (eg manual shutdown requested) why the server was stopped.

You can also get the database engine to write its own console log to file with the

`-o <filename>`

server start up option - that may give you more detailed information.

It's important to check that your connections aren't specifying the AutoStop connection parameter or the Stop Database After Last Disconnect ODBC setting. This only applies if you are asking the connection to automatically start the database engine if it is not already running - NOT if you are running the database engine as a service.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same problem.I got very good input from Justin. Thanks :)
I checked my windows event log and found that I could not start my services because my "master.dat" was corrupted, which is one of the system defined database. (So I checked this file, which you will get in "C:\Sybase\data" in case of windows OR where ever you have mentioned your path while installing.)
I replaced master.dat file with the correct one from a colleague.
Everything seems to be working fine now!